# How do I solve $\frac{df(x)}{d(-x)}$ for a differentiable function $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to solve$\frac{df(x)}{d(-x)}$ for a differentiable function $f(x)$. For example, I am trying to see if it is true that:

$$
\frac{dx^3}{d(-x)} = -\frac{dx^3}{d(x)} = -3x^2
$$

Does anyone have any idea what Leibniz notation would say here? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is a function of $x$ and you set $x = -t$, then you can use the chain rule:

$$\dfrac{df}{dt} = \dfrac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{df}{dx} $$

because $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -1$.